# Is it necessary to use PHP in order to create an automated form for a web page?

Tags: php, forms

Is there an easy way to set up an automated form on a web page that sends info to a specific email address after being filled out? I don't know much about php, but someone mentioned it as a possibility. I would like to create a form that gets filled out and sent to a server email address automatically. Preferably without having to learn anything besides html/css.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not need PHP but you need some server code.

The most common one used to be [FormMail](http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html) for CGI.
There is now a [FormMail implementation for PHP](http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php) as well.

Ask your web host what they support. They usually have examples
as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a [lot of tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+contact+form+tutorial) out there.

Heck, they even have [generators](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+contact+form+generator) that will create the script for you.

If you want to code it yourself, php's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function is what you will probably use.

Good luck.